# Bondholder vs purchaser of bond

Tags: bonds

Kindly clarify if the term bondholder refers to the bond issuing authority  or the person who purchases the bond.

Context: if there's inflation in the economy, bondholder will lose and the person who purchase the bond will get a higher return.

Comment: You would need to show the context, but the natural meaning is the person who owns the bond at that point in time

Comment: The contect you provided is wrong: Bondholder and "person who purchase the bond" means the same thing

Comment: The bondholder refers to the person who holds the bond at present. The person who purchases the bond refers to, well, the person who purchases the bond from the current bondholder.

Answer (score 0):

A bondholder is the owner of a bond. It may have been purchased in the secondary market.

Answer (score 0):

The Bondholder is the one who "holds" the bond, meaning that he is the owner of that bond.